# How do I know which tenses to use if I start a sentence with "What if I told you"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, past-tense, present-tense, writing

My understanding is if I start a sentence with "what if I told you" then the following sentence should stay in the past but I'm confused because I don't want to tell a past but sometimes I just want to say something theoretically. So can anyone explain which tense I could use, do I have to stay consistently in the past? or the following sentence can be in the present form.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following examples:

"What if I told you.....

1. that I came first in class. (past)
2. that I am sitting in first class. (present continuous)
3. that I have won the lottery. (present perfect)
4. that she will travel to London tomorrow (future)
5. that I play football on Saturdays. (present)
6. that he had been crossing the street when he was knocked down. (mixed)

and so on.

You can use whatever tense you choose. It all depends on what you want to say.